# How are process assigned with privileges in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm little confused about "process" in linux. How does linux assign privileges to processes that are created under different users? Say if a root user starts a process (say jboss server)
does the jboss server will have root privileges? or will have a seperate privilege? can anybody suggest a site that have information about linux process.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is usually run by a specific user. if you log in yourself and run the program, it will run with the same privileges as yourself.

So in your case if you run a root user starts jboss server, jboss server process will have root privileges.

I think you can find a lot of information in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305416/how-does-a-process-in-linux-decides-privileges-allotted-to-it?rq=1

Comment: The above link speaks about effective userid, how to get the effect userid of a proces if I know that processid of a process?

Comment: To find the effective user id of process user "ps -ef" will give you effective user id of all the process running.To find the effective user of a specific process say "jboss" you can use "ps -ef | grep jboss",thank you very much TheEwook for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help ;)